# Best way to handle arg validation

Tags: python

Is there any downside to validating args this way:

```
if x in [1,2,3]:
    ...
```

Or is it better to do the more traditional way:

```
if x == 1 or x == 2 or x == 3:
    ...
```

Comment: Frankly the first is way more elegant!

Comment: *traditional way* ? Where did you get that? The first form is the most pythonic

Comment: `if x in {1,2,3}`

Comment: The main determiner is, which one is most easily read and maintained by the people who work with the code?  **I** prefer the set notation.

Comment: By "traditional", you appear to mean "How you do things in C because you have no higher-level data structures to work with."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only downside I could see is performance.

On my machine, windows 8.1, python 3.7.3, via ipython, I get:

```
x = 4

%timeit x in [1,2,3]
183 ns ± 19 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000000 loops each)

%timeit x == 1 or x == 2 or x == 3
295 ns ± 19.7 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)
```

So it seems both cleaner and faster.

FYI, using a set, I get:

```
%timeit x in {1,2,3}
116 ns ± 7 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000000 loops each)
```